# Take selected DDL value an use as parameter for actionlink

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC view with a few dropdown lists. There is some custom validation on there that under certain conditions will show an action link by the side of the drop down list. These action links will pop up a modal window with information related to the choice made in the dropdown list.

My problem is that I can seem to see how to take the value chosen from the dropdown and get it in to my ajax request!!

Here is my code: (dropdown)

```
        <div id="holderlist">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(i => i.holderid, (SelectList)ViewData["holdersList"], "", new { @class = "chosenlist" })   
    </div>
```

(action link)

```
 <div id="add" style="display:none;">

    @Html.ActionLink("Actions", "existingOfficers", "Roles",
        new { id = ?????<how do I get DDL chosen ID here>  },
        new { @class = "openDialog", dialog_id = "productDetail", dialog_title = "Workflow Centre" })
    </div>
```

(ajax request)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".openDialog").live("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("<div></div>")
  .addClass("dialog")
  .attr("id", $(this).attr("dialog-id"))
  .appendTo("body")
  .dialog({
      title: $(this).attr("dialog-title"),
      close: function () { $(this).remove() },
      modal: true,
       width: 706,                 
       height: 300
  })
  .load(this.href);
    });

    $(".close").live("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
    });
});
```

What I cant do is get the ID set to the ID of the value chosen in the DDL. The DDL value isn't at this point stored in the database as this is essentially a new input form.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950124/asp-net-mvc-actionlink

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function($) {
$('.helpButton').each(function() {  
    $.data(this, 'dialog', 
      $(this).next('.helpDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,  
        modal: true,  
        title: 'Info',  
        width: 600,  
        height: 400,  
        position: [200,0],  
        draggable: false  
      })
    );  
  }).click(function() {  
      $.data(this, 'dialog').dialog('open');  
      return false;  
  });  
});  ​
```

[You can test here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZwLcE/736/)